# Can we use VBA to get Properties of all Connection Strings in an Excel File?

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't used Excel in a while, but now I need to. I've been Googling for a bit, but I can't seem to find an answer for my question. Basically, I'm trying to find a way to get the details from the properties of ALL connection strings, marrying other data sources to Excel. Here is a screen shot of what I want to grab. So, if there are several connections strings, I want to collect the details of each one.

[image]

This is what I have experimented with.

```
Sub List_Connections()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim listObj As ListObject
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim qtName As String
    Dim n As Long
    Dim wbConn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim qcSheet As Worksheet, r As Long
    
    'Either operate on this macro workbook
    'Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    'Or operate on the active workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Set qcSheet = GetWbSheet(wb, "Queries Conns")
    If qcSheet Is Nothing Then
        With wb
            Set qcSheet = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count))
            qcSheet.Name = "Queries Conns"
        End With
    End If
    
    qcSheet.Cells.Clear
    r = 1
    qcSheet.Cells(r, "A").Value = "QueryTables"
    qcSheet.Cells(r, "A").Font.Bold = True
    r = r + 1
    qcSheet.Cells(r, "A").Resize(, 3).Value = Array("Worksheet", "QueryTable Name", "QueryTable CommandText")
    r = r + 1
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If Not ws Is qcSheet Then
            qcSheet.Cells(r, "A").Value = ws.Name
            n = 0
            For Each qt In ws.QueryTables
                qcSheet.Cells(r + n, "B").Value = qt.Name
                qcSheet.Cells(r + n, "C").Value = qt.CommandText
                n = n + 1
            Next
            If n = 0 Then n = 1
            r = r + n
        End If
    Next
    
    r = r + 1
    qcSheet.Cells(r, "A").Value = "ListObjects"
    qcSheet.Cells(r, "A").Font.Bold = True
    r = r + 1
    qcSheet.Cells(r, "A").Resize(, 4).Value = Array("Worksheet", "Name", "QueryTable Name", "QueryTable CommandText")
    r = r + 1
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If Not ws Is qcSheet Then
            n = 0
            For Each listObj In ws.ListObjects
                qcSheet.Cells(r + n, "A").Value = ws.Name
                qcSheet.Cells(r + n, "B").Value = listObj.Name
                Set qt = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set qt = listObj.QueryTable
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not qt Is Nothing Then
                    qtName = "Undefined"
                    On Error Resume Next
                    qtName = qt.Name
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    qcSheet.Cells(r + n, "C").Value = qtName
                    qcSheet.Cells(r + n, "D").Value = qt.CommandText
                End If
                n = n + 1
            Next
            r = r + n
        End If
        
    Next
    
    r = r + 1
    qcSheet.Cells(r, "A").Value = "Workbook Connections"
    qcSheet.Cells(r, "A").Font.Bold = True
    r = r + 1
    qcSheet.Cells(r, "A").Resize(, 2).Value = Array("Name", "CommandText")
    r = r + 1
    
    n = 0
    For Each wbConn In wb.Connections
        qcSheet.Cells(r + n, "A").Value = wbConn.Name
        Select Case wbConn.Type
            Case Is = xlConnectionTypeODBC
                qcSheet.Cells(r + n, "B").Value = wbConn.ODBCConnection.CommandText
            Case Is = xlConnectionTypeOLEDB
                qcSheet.Cells(r + n, "B").Value = wbConn.OLEDBConnection.CommandText
        End Select
        n = n + 1
    Next

End Sub


Private Function GetWbSheet(wb As Workbook, sheetName As String) As Worksheet
    Set GetWbSheet = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWbSheet = wb.Worksheets(sheetName)
    On Error Resume Next
End Function
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

I don't know what the final code would look like, but if Excel knows what the connection string is, I think it should be exposed in some way, and accessible through VBA. Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: I just updated my original post.

Comment: Did you check out `wbConn.OLEDBConnection.Connection`? • It is a bit unclear what exactly your question is.